# Hat-Matching Problem, Probability of exactly 1

Tags: probability

A group of n professors attend a meeting, all wearing hats. At the beginning of the meeting, they put their hats away. At the end of the meeting, each picks a hat at random. The probability that **none** of them gets the right hat is:

$\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!\:}-...+\frac{\left(-1\right)^n1}{n!}$

The probability that **at least** one professor will get the right hat is:

$1-(\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!\:}-...+\frac{\left(-1\right)^n1}{n!})=1-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$

What is the probability that **exactly** one of them gets the right hat?

Comment: can you find the probability of at least 2 ?

Comment: A generalization: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/574613/probability-that-exactly-k-of-n-people-matched-their-hats-sross-p63-ex-2g?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E_i$ be the event that professor $i$ gets their hat back. First find $P(E_1\cap E_2^c\cap E_3^c\cap \dots\cap E_n^c)$, the probability that the first professor gets their hat back and no one else does. The final answer is $n$ times this probability.
$$
\begin{align}
P(E_1\cap E_2^c\cap E_3^c\cap \dots\cap E_n^c) 
=P(E_2^c\cap \dots \cap E_n^c|E_1)P(E_1)
\end{align}
$$
Now, given that $E_1$ has occurred, we are just down to the $n-1$ professor situation, so 
$$
P(E_2^c\cap \dots \cap E_n^c|E_1)= \frac1{2!}-\frac1{3!}+\dots +\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}
$$
Putting this all together gives you your answer.

Comment: What if the 8th out of n professor picks the right hat? Does that change the answer?

Comment: That's why you multiply by $n$ (see third sentence). Letting $F_i$ be the event that the $i^{th}$ professor gets their hat back and no one else does, you want $P(F_1)+\dots+P(F_n)=nP(F_1)$.@user485656

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Why do we multiply by n?

Answer (score 3):

There are $n$ people who might be lucky enough to get the right hat, we require that the other $n-1$ do not. So there are $n d(n-1)$ where $d(m)$ denotes the number of derrangements of $m$ elements. The probability is $ \color{blue}{\frac{d(n-1)}{(n-1)!}}$.